# Telegram bot only allowed to post upon events?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

It seems like Telegram bot revolves around the idea of reacting to human events (whether in channel or private messages).

Is there any way to have the Telegram bot post on a channel independently?

Am I really forced to use webhooks for this?

I would like my bot to read blockchain operations and post these on my particular channel regardless of human events.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `polling` (instead webhook) in the Python Telegram Bot framework

```
updater = Updater('token', use_context=True)

dp = updater.dispatcher
updater.start_polling()

# initiate message from backend
dp.bot.send_message(chat_id='xxxx', text='Hello')
```

As you notice you need a valid chat_id which you get when there is an incoming message/command or the bot is added to a group. You will need to capture that event and save it.