# How to make Python-Telegram_bot send a message without getting a commad?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm Making a telegram bot using Python-Telegram-bot. I wanna make it send a message to one specific user (myself in this case) to select an option. after that, it should take that option as a command and work as usual. but after 30 min... it should send me the same message making me choose an option just like before. How can I make i work?

```
def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    user = update.message.from_user.username
    print(user)
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text= "Choose an option. ('/option1' , '/option 2', '/...')")


def main():

    updater = Updater("<MY-BOT-TOKEN>", use_context=True)

    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want this to run without getting the /start command (the update). but after this... there will be normal functions that'll get updates and after 30 min I wanna run this "start" function again without getting an update.

Comment: You've placed your **private BOT token** in the question. I removed it, but it's still visible in the history. Consider renewing the token at @botFather to prevent other people abusing it!

Comment: I have answered something similar here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64681056/9095551. You are on the right track using `polling`, you need to get and store the `chat_id` during the first interaction then you can trigger messages from your app (in a background thread -ie every 30 min)

Comment: @BeppeC What if I want to run start() every 30 minutes? it asks for the missing parameters.

Comment: @BeppeC When you'll run it for the first time... save the update and context in a variable. then pass it as parameters every 30 min. make sure you save the update from the same chat.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get the `bot` object either from the updater or the dispatcher:

```
updater = Updater('<bot-token>')
updater.bot.sendMessage(chat_id='<user-id>', text='Hello there!')

# alternative:
updater.dispatcher.bot.sendMessage(chat_id='<user-id>', text='Hello there!')
```

Answer (score 11):

## v20.x

Since version [`v20.x`](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/releases/tag/v20.0a0), there has been a switch to `asyncio`. `Updater` has been changed, it no longer takes the bot token as a parameter. Instead, using a builder pattern, the `ApplicationBuilder` is expected to be used to create your telegram bot.

Here are two approaches of sending messages to arbitrary chats.

```py
import asyncio
import telegram
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder

# using telegram.Bot
async def send(chat, msg):
    await telegram.Bot('<bot-token>').sendMessage(chat_id=chat, text=msg)

asyncio.run(send('<chat-id>', 'Hello there!'))

# using ApplicationBuilder
async def send_more(chat, msg):
    application = ApplicationBuilder().token('<bot-token>').build()
    await application.bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat, text=msg)

asyncio.run(send_more('<chat-id>', 'Hello there!'))
```

Comment: Worked for me, I'm using `python-telegram-bot==20.7`

Comment: works but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75707605/cant-get-telegram-bot-to-send-messages-to-user-and-run-polling-loop-at-the-same