# python-telegram-bot send message without using update and context

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I want my bot to send a message to the telegram chat when I am active on my computer. I've wrote other functions that use this fuction to send messages.

```
# Function to send messages back to chat
def sendmessage(update, context, message):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=message)
```

This however uses update and context from the dispatcher and handler.

The function I want to send a message runs in a separate thread and is not using the dispatcher or handler. Thus I cannot use above function. I can't seem to figure out how to send a message without the use of update and context.

What I have now:

```
def user_returned():
    row_list = []
    with open('log.csv') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for row in csv_reader:
            row_list.append(row)
    last_line = row_list[-1]
    second_to_last_line = row_list[-2]
    print(last_line['active'], second_to_last_line['active'])
    if last_line['active'] == 'True' and second_to_last_line['active'] == 'False':
        message = 'user is back'
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=message)
    else:
        message = 'still gone'
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=message)
```

Comment: I managed to find a solution to my problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65349950/how-to-make-python-telegram-bot-send-a-message-without-getting-a-commad

Answer (score 1):

```
import telegram

bot=telegram.Bot(token=bot_token)
chat=123456

bot.sendMessage(chat, msg)
```