# How do I access the chat_id and save it for further execution?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I have created a notification bot, which updates the temperature of the room in telegram group when someone in the group initiates with /start command, so it saves the chat_id of the initiator and notifies in the group.

Is there any possibility, when I upload this code on the server, which executes every 10 minutes should notify the temperature in the telegram group without asking for chat_id every time?

For this, to work should I store the chat_id of the initiator?
How Can I do this?? or any other possibility??

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64679299/telegram-bot-only-allowed-to-post-upon-events/64681056#64681056. The idea is to get the chat_id the first time (this is necessary) and then run polling from a backend thread