# How to get chat id in telegram bot without message from user? Is it even real?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I am making a **telegram bot** who will work like **schedule** and it is deployed on **heroku**. When server is restarting, chat id is clearing and the bot is not working

So I have a question. Can I somehow get **chat id** without user message? And is it even real?

Comment: User must interact with bot in order to get chat id of the user

Comment: You need to chat with the user (at least once) then save the chat_id for future usage, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64681056/9095551

Comment: Welcome! Could you add some minimal reproducible code? In that way it's easier for us to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

you must back up those **id**'s and your **session** files

the session file contains information about all your interactions with telegram (chats , massages ,....)

before server restarts , save the session files
remember saving the session files and coping them again to their directory after the restart is like nothing has happend to the bot , because everything is saved into these files .

connect your bot to a database system . mysql ,.....
or just save chat id (or peer id ) number (which is inside the update array ) into a file (txt , json ,...) then use them after server restarts .

if you lose the session files it's like the memory of bot is erased