# Does it possible to run a function/callback without typing any command using python-telegram-bot?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I developing a telegram bot using [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) and I'm trying to send a message using a function/callback without typing/entering any command. The server itself runs locally on my machine. I also have stored every `user_id` who sent the `/start` command into SQLite DB, so I can broadcast my message every time the server is online or about to offline.

My question is, does it possible to send a message every time the server is online without calling any callback?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# pylint: disable=C0116,W0613
# This program is dedicated to the public domain under the CC0 license.

"""
Simple Bot to reply to Telegram messages.

First, a few handler functions are defined. Then, those functions are passed to
the Dispatcher and registered at their respective places.
Then, the bot is started and runs until we press Ctrl-C on the command line.

Usage:
Basic Echobot example, repeats messages.
Press Ctrl-C on the command line or send a signal to the process to stop the
bot.
"""

import sqlite_command
import logging

from telegram import Update, ForceReply
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackContext

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO
)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


# Define a few command handlers. These usually take the two arguments update and
# context.
def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Send a message when the command /start is issued."""
    user = update.effective_user
    update.message.reply_markdown_v2(
        fr'Hi {user.mention_markdown_v2()}\!',
        reply_markup=ForceReply(selective=True),
    )


def help_command(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Send a message when the command /help is issued."""
    update.message.reply_text('Help!')


def echo(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Echo the user message."""
    update.message.reply_text(update.message.text)


def main() -> None:
    """Start the bot."""
    # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
    updater = Updater("TOKEN")

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    # Send a message without calling a callback
    ids = sqlite_command.query_ids()
    for chat_id in ids:
        dispatcher.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id,text='server online')

    # on different commands - answer in Telegram
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help_command))

    # on non command i.e message - echo the message on Telegram
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, echo))

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
    # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, I've solved this problem! I found some similar questions with the exact answers I looking for.

I can use: `dp.bot.send_message(chat_id='xxxx', text='Hello')` thanks to [Beppe C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64681056/13526237)

Either: `updater.dispatcher.bot.sendMessage(chat_id='<user-id>', text='Hello there!')` by [scai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65512147/13526237)